# How to validate the multiple forms in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I Want to make validation for the table which have some fields in a row. The  row will repeat. I'm not able to do the validation as in the form, because the rows are being `ngRepeat`. To make validation in from tag's name attribute will repeat and it is makes complicit in all rows.

https://plnkr.co/edit/5PUDBxMR184IQnDR9LzR?p=preview

```
$scope.addStudent = function(){
var newStud = {};
angular.copy( $scope.objMod, newStud);
$scope.students.push(newStud);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `track by $index`

```
<tr ng-repeat="stud in students track by $index">          
      <td><input type="text" name="name" id="id-{{$index}}" ng-model="stud.name" length="80"><span ng-show="form-stud.name.$error">Error!</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age-{{$index}}" ng-model="stud.age" max="30" min="8"></td>
      <td><input type="email" name="mail" id="mail-{{$index}}" ng-model="stud.mail"></td>       
</tr>
```

You have the ids now. You can run a for loop for validation before adding.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if you're going to `ng-repeat` over something, you should not give it a non-dynamic `id`.  Now every time you add a row, each one has the same `id`.  What's the point in even having it, if that's the case?

Second, I recommend looking into [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and using this as a form, because then you can set up validators for the entire form, no matter how many fields you've got.

Comment: thanks, yeah... I know can do with many fields. I was stuck with just how to handle those. your( @sisyphus  and you) answers helpful...